# python XlsxWriter piechart data_labels

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a pie chart that I am trying to add category name next to percentage value outside of my chart.

Here is my code:

```
pie_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'pie'})

pie_chart.set_legend({'none': True})

pie_chart.add_series({
    'name':'USD transactions per currency',
    'categories':'=Totals!$E$2:$E$7',
    'values':'=Totals!$K$2:$K$7',
    'data_labels':{'value':True,'category_name':True,'position':'outside_end'}
    })

pie_chart.set_style(10)

worksheet1.insert_chart('F9',pie_chart)

writer.save()
```

[image: Pie chart]

I would like something like this:

[image: What I want]

When I run my code, the category name tag is not checked and I can't find how to get it checked to get the format I want.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `category` instead of `category_name`.

See the XlsxsWriter docs on [Chart Data Labels](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html#chart-series-option-data-labels).